# Introduction in Latin

Tags: vocabulary

I want to find the proper correlative/translation for the phrase "introduce yourself" in latin. Can you think of the phrase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Latin has the verb [*introducere*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=introduco&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) which, perhaps surprisingly, works here as a translation for "introduce".
The verb [*inducere*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=induco&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) seems to only work for introducing thoughts but not people, so it is not suitable for your case.

My Finnish dictionary gives *introducere* as the only option but the book never cites examples.
L&S cite the example *Catonem induxi senem disputantem* from [*De amicitia*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0040%3Asection%3D4) and it seems to introduce the person as a topic rather than introducing socially in the way you mean.

My best suggestion for "to introduce yourself" is *te introducere* but it does not feel like a perfect hit.

Comment: Smith and Hall provide the relevant attestation: [Cic. *Att*. 1.16.5 (it says 2, but PHI has 5)](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/57/15/4356-4361,4365-4374@1#15). This (and the others it recommends) feel like "introduce" in the networking sense, as in the English "to make an introduction."